# Resource for dumping entire stack/call trace for comparison

Tags: intellij-idea, stack-trace, java-ee-6, thread-dump

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 to debug the processing difference between two very similar executions of a Legacy Java6EE app. I want to capture the full call and/or stack trace of an application, maybe a thread dump as well since it may be offloading some work to another thread. I'm trying to test only one difference in parameters to determine why it fails with one more explicit parameter set. I'm primarily concerned with the difference in logic followed and maybe see if the query executions are different.

However, I can't find a resource for this process. I'm only able to find the importation of external traces and thread dumps for comparison in the Analysis tab from the JetBrains forum and guides, but nothing showing how to get the initial trace aside from hitting a breakpoint and exporting that small chunk.

Comment: [Dump threads](https://i.imgur.com/jd62ewk.png) button may help.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder I'll try that. I saw https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.1/analyzing-external-stacktraces.html and I was looking for the button with a south-west right-angled line containing a north-east arrow similar to |➚_ but I couldn't find it.